# Interthread communication between producer and consumer threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am trying to learn inter thread communication where I am using BlockingQueue.

I have written a producer which generate TaskId and insert it into BlockingQueue.

Now I have 2 consumers threads (name "1" and "0"). If taskId is odd, it is consumed by Thread "1" else "2".

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

                while (queue.peek() != null && !name.equals(String.valueOf(queue.peek().intValue() % 2 ))) {

                try {
                    System.out.println(name + ",consumed," + queue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i make that check also here?

Comment: If name is 1 and first entry is 5, your check name.equals(String.valueOf(queue.peek().intValue() % 2 )) returns true and the thread will wait. Shouldn't it be !name.equals(String.valueOf(queue.peek().intValue() % 2 ))? Assuming you want 5 to be processed by the thread 1.

Comment: Thanks. I made that change. But still my problem is different.

Comment: This code is bad from the beginning due to the fact that `BlockingQueue` is not useful if tasks must be consumed by *specific* consumers. Normally you don't need any (extra) synchronization when using a `BlockingQueue`. This code is filled with custom synchronized and `wait/notify`, essentially copying the functionality of `BlockingQueue`, but in a shoddier way. And don't get me started on using the thread's name for logic... From a design point of view this code is terrible.

Comment: So in case of specific consumers, what should I use instead of BlockingQueue?

Comment: The whole point of `BlockingQueue` is to block when the queue is empty (or full, if size limited queue). You're programming against that by using `poll()`, because you can't block not knowing which consumer the payload is for. Then you end up with this "the list is empty, but I can't block, but busy waiting makes this a bad solution" situation.

Comment: @Nicky a queue per consumer allows consumer threads to sleep if there's nothing in the queue. Then you're using `BlockingQueue` correctly. You're writing a lot of extra code for the sole purpose of trying to shoehorn a single queue where multiple are needed.

Comment: @Nicky not sure what your actual use case is, does having a single consumer that waits on the queue and invoking odd/even threads depending on retrieved value work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I am thinking, there could be other better ways also:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while (true) {

            while (queue.peek() == null) {
                //some sleep time
            }

            synchronized (lock) {
                while (queue.peek() != null && !name.equals(String.valueOf(queue.peek().intValue() % 2 ))) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(queue.peek() != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(name + ",consumed," + queue.take());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Another Way: To have anotherLock that will be notified by producer thread whenever element is added to queue.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while (true) {

            synchronized (anotherLock) {
                while (queue.peek() == null) {
                    anotherLock.wait();
                }
            }

            synchronized (lock) {
                while (queue.peek() != null && !name.equals(String.valueOf(queue.peek().intValue() % 2 ))) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(queue.peek() != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(name + ",consumed," + queue.take());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Kayaman I agree first method is not a good way. Added one more way to see it in a different way.